# Visual Studio 2019 compile error with OpenSSL 1.1.1k

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, openssl

I am trying to compile my Visual Studio WIN32 project with the latest version of OpenSSL (v1.1.1k) but I am encountering the following compiler errors below in regards to refcount.h. In refcount.h, the compiler is complaining about an illegal conversion from volatile int* to volatile long* with the InterlockedExchangeAdd() function, which is in the 3rd else if preprocessor directive block with the #elif defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER>=1200. Aside from commenting out the else if block to force it into else block with the correct logic, I tried playing around with various Visual Studio settings as well as OpenSSL options but with no success. I am wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue or if there is anyway to fix the issue without modifying the file.

1>C:\openssl\openssl-1.1.1k\include\internal\refcount.h(116,42): error C2664: 'long _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile long *,long)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'volatile int *' to 'volatile long *'
1>C:\openssl\openssl-1.1.1k\include\internal\refcount.h(116,36): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\intrin0.h(189,1): message : see declaration of '_InterlockedExchangeAdd'
1>C:\openssl\openssl-1.1.1k\include\internal\refcount.h(122,43): error C2664: 'long _InterlockedExchangeAdd(volatile long *,long)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'volatile int *' to 'volatile long *'
1>C:\openssl\openssl-1.1.1k\include\internal\refcount.h(122,36): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\intrin0.h(189,1): message : see declaration of '_InterlockedExchangeAdd'

Extra information:

Visual Studio Community 2019,
Windows SDK Version: 10.0,
Platform Toolset v142

OpenSSL 1.1.1k built with following options:
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --debug no-engine

Comment: Please show the output from running the `cl` command with no arguments.

Comment: I added the output to the problem description but I don't see any useful info out of it. Let me know if you want to see anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I asked for the output from running the `cl` command with no arguments...I don't see that in your updated text?

Comment: C:\>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30038.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]